# How to add all values in a certain column?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I want to add all the 3rd fields from each line and produce the result.

Below is the way I solved the problem

```
sum=0
grep '2016Feb' input.txt|awk -F\- '{print $3}'|while read LINE; do
sum = $(expr $sum + $LINE)
done
echo $sum
```

Is there a better way of solving the problem than my code? Possible a command that solves the problem @ command line itself?

For a file like:

```
$ cat input.txt
Feb2016-2016-110
Feb2016-2016-20
Feb2016-2016-220
Feb2016-2016-140
Feb2016-2016-100
```

The output is: `590`.

Comment: I doubt this is working, since `sum = $(expr $sum + $LINE)` is not a valid syntax. Spaces around `=` should be removed.

Comment: Agreed fedorqui. Not implemented the above code. But the logic and way it is solved is definitely correct leaving out syntax corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the field separator to the dash and sum the third column:

```
$ awk -F- '{sum+=$3} END{print sum+0}' file
590                               ^^
#                     in case there are no matching lines, print 0
```

Since it looks like you are just counting those lines that contain the text "Feb2016", you can also add a filter:

```
awk -F- '/Feb2016/{sum+=$3} END{print sum+0}' file
#        ^^^^^^^^^
#        just on lines containing the string "Feb2016"
```

Comment: This is effective. Thanks Fedorqui.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat data 
Feb2016-2016-110
Feb2016-2016-20
Feb2016-2016-220
Feb2016-2016-140
Feb2016-2016-100
$ cut -d - -f 3 data | paste -s -d '+' | bc
590
$
```

Comment: why piping so much if awk alone can handle it?

Comment: @fedorqui yes true, above pipeline spawns 3 processes; i was about to post the `awk` version but you beat me by few seconds .. so just posted another version

Comment: In that case, `cut` would be more light-weight.